# Removing list margin

Tags: lists, indentation

I have an `enumerate` in which the items are paragraphs (sometimes more then 1 per item) and the paragraphs are indented after the label.
How can I change the behaviour so that from the second line of the item, it should start with normal margin (below the label)?

I am using `book` class.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `\itemindent` length to make it equal to `\labelwidth+\labelsep`, and perhaps also change the `\leftamrgin`. The [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package allows you to do those modifications easily. A little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left,labelwidth=1.5em,itemindent=\labelwidth+\labelsep,leftmargin=0.3cm]
  \item \lipsum[1-2]
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```